# How to replace NaN in single column with 0 based on index

Tags: python, pandas

Very new to coding so please excuse my lack of knowledge 
I currently have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
date         A     B    C    
2006-11-01   NaN   1    NaN
2016-11-02   NaN   NaN  1
2016-11-03   1     NaN  NaN
2016-11-04   NaN   1    NaN
2016-11-05   NaN   1    NaN
2016-11-06   NaN   NaN  NaN
2016-11-07   NaN   1    NaN
```

What I want to do, for example, is: 
 
replace all NaN's in column A with 0 for all dates after 2016-11-03 and be able to do this same thing for each column but with different corresponding dates.

I have tried

```
for col in df:
    if col == 'A' & 'date' > '2016-11-03':
        value_1 = {'A':0}
        df = df.fillna(value=value_1)
```

but I received this error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str'`

I'm sure this has to do with my lack of knowledge but I'm not sure how to proceed.


EDIT: what I am looking for is something like this:

```
date         A     B    C    
2006-11-01   NaN   1    NaN
2016-11-02   NaN   NaN  1
2016-11-03   1     NaN  NaN
2016-11-04   0     1    NaN
2016-11-05   0     1    NaN
2016-11-06   0     NaN  NaN
2016-11-07   0     1    NaN
```

Comment: I think you mean to be using `and`, not `&`. `x & y` is a bitwise operation with higher precedence than `==` and `>`, not a logical one. Pandas overloads it to be logical.

Comment: Is it just coincidence that you are filling `A` after the first non-null index, or do you need to do this in general for all columns?

Comment: @EdwardMinnix ah I see thanks for correcting me! I'm still learning so anything helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition consists of two parts: being after a certain date and being a NaN.

```
condition = (df['date'] > '2016-11-03') & df['A'].isnull()
```

Now, choose the rows that match the condition and make the respective items in the column A equal 0:

```
df.loc[condition, 'A'] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.loc[(df.date > '2016-11-03') & (df['A'].isnull()),'A'] = 0;
```

Output:

```
A   B   C   date
0   NaN 1.0 NaN 2006-11-01
1   NaN NaN 1.0 2016-11-02
2   1.0 NaN NaN 2016-11-03
3   0.0 1.0 NaN 2016-11-04
4   0.0 1.0 NaN 2016-11-05
5   0.0 NaN NaN 2016-11-06
6   0.0 1.0 NaN 2016-11-07
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use fillna, replace empty rows with zero

> `if condition == 'A':
>
>      fillna(0, inplace = True)`